# How do I get a controller's POST action methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, reflection

I need to unit test my POST action methods, so I need a list of them. I am using reflection to find those methods with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`.

```
// get controller's methods
typeof(FooController).GetMethods()

// get controller's action methods
.Where(q => q.IsPublic && q.IsVirtual && q.ReturnType == typeof(ActionResult))

// get actions decorated with AcceptVerbsAttribute
.Where(q => q.CustomAttributes
  .Any(w => (w.AttributeType == _typeof(AcceptVerbsAttribute)))
  )

// ...everything is ok till here...

// filter for those with the HttpVerbs.Post ctor arg
.Where(q => q.CustomAttributes
  .Any(w => w.ConstructorArguments.Any(e => e.Value.Equals(HttpVerbs.Post))))
;
```

This however gives me an empty list. The problem is in the last check for the attribute's ctor. How do I fix it?

It is worth noting there are two ways for declaring the action's method as POST: using `AcceptVerbsAttribute` as above, and `HttpPostAttribute`.

Comment: As stated, this seems to be an observation rather than a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following:

```
w => w.ConstructorArguments.Any(e => e.Value.Equals(HttpVerbs.Post))
```

To

```
w => w.ConstructorArguments.Any(e => ((HttpVerbs) e.Value) == HttpVerbs.Post)
```

And that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [HttpPost] attribute instead of [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] and simplify your expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.108).aspx